# How to sort products with the same price in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In the `show` view of my `products` am using the following function to link to the next product (ordered by `price`):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :user

  def next
    Product.where("user_id = ? AND price > ?", user_id, price).order("price ASC").first 
  end

end
```

This function works as long as all products differ in price. The moment two products have the *same* price though, the function no longer works because it is always looking for a *higher* price.

How can I make it that a `user` can  click through **all** his products using the function above, even when some products do not differ in price?

I tried replacing `>` with `>=` but that will always return the same one product, leaving the function essentially useless.

Can anybody help?

Comment: trying this `Product.order("price ASC").where("user_id = ? AND price > ?", user_id, price).first`

Comment: @Monk_Code: Unfortunately, that's not working here either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method can only work if the products are strictly ordered. A solution could be to sort them by price first and next by id (the condition a bit more complex also):

```
def next
  Product.where("user_id = :user_id AND (price > :price OR (price = :price AND id > :id))", user_id: user_id, price: price, id: id)
    .order("price ASC, id ASC").first 
end
```

If the products have a [unique](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) name or label, you could use this attribute instead on the id, so the products with the same price are sorted alphabetically, that could make more sense then the id.

Comment: Awesome, that works! Thank you. Can you explain why you are using symbols like `:user_id` inside the where method? I haven't seen that before and I am browsing through the documentation right now.

Comment: Because `:price` and `:id` appears 2 times in the SQL request, so there would have been five `?` followed by five paremeters. It's more readable like this.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Greater than `>=` plus different `product_id`

```
def next
  Product.
    where("id <> ?", id).
    where("user_id = ?", user_id).
    where("price >= ?", price).
    order("price ASC").
    first 
end
```

Comment: If there is 2 products with the same price, this method will go back and forth between these 2 products because there not sorted by id.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm struggling with here right now. Can't get it to work.